# Is it possible to open multiple Snowflake sessions at the same time to execute long SQL statements from python?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am wondering whether it is possible to parallelize some of my database queries on Snowflake that I am running from python with sqlalchemy.

My setup is as follows:

- I have a long SQL file that creates several temporary tables that I execute via `conn.execute(SQL)`
- I have a query that fetches the results from the last temp table and stores them in a pandas df (with`pd.read_sql`)
- I want to run the SQL file with different parameters (say 100 different time frames)

What I am looking for is a way to parallelize the execution of the SQL file with different sets of parameters in order to save time. As there are temporary tables in the SQL file, however, I would have to run each statement in different sessions so that the temp tables change dependent on the parameters I am varying. Of course, a new session would also require a single authentification per session (that I intend on solving by authentifying with key pairs).

Comment: It would also depend on how stressful the query is on the cluster. If it's ramping up and using most of the CPU/RAM then creating separate sessions probably won't speed anything up

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake can run queries in parallel. Unfortunately, there is no async connector in python to snowflake as of 25th of April. Otherwise this code would work:

```py
def _read_sql_query(con, stmt):
    return pd.read_sql_query(stmt, con)


async def get_df(stmt, engine):
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        data = await conn.run_sync(_read_sql_query, stmt)
    return data

asyn_engine = create_async_engine('...snowflake connection')
stmt = select(MyTable)

data = get_df(stmt, asyn_engine )
```